# replicate this javascript animation effect

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried various methods trying to make a copy of this animation mentioned in the website:

```
http://visitbruges.be/
```

I notice that the line 103 in the source is where it starts the animation effect:

```
<div id="sunmoon">
    <div class="star" id="s1"></div>
    <div class="star" id="s2"></div>
    <div class="star" id="s3"></div>
    <div class="star" id="s4"></div>
    <div class="star" id="s5"></div>
    <div class="star" id="s6"></div>
    <div id="sun"><div></div></div>
    <div id="moon"><div></div></div>
</div>
```

There are only two .js files but none of them shows why it still calls the images from the parent website. I tried copy-paste the source and then placing all the images/css/js in the same structure as the website but that didn't work. the images in the animation are still called from the online website. Looked through every line of code in the js files but i still can't figure it out. Tried Cmd+S and saved it but it saved the codes which doesn't work the way it should.

When i completely go offline, the images are not called but when i go online, the images appear in the localhost copy i've made and it works the way it should. It's like the javascript is encoded somehow and i'm unable to figure out where and how.

Any leads would be really helpful. thanks.

Comment: Try something yourself, perhaps just google for copy-paste scripts, or at least try to make sense of the scripts on the linked page (setting breakpoints is a good idea, for example)

Comment: Some examination with Firefox Inspector showed that the stars, sun & moon have a CSS animation called `spin`. Also the images are loaded by a `background` property, from `/images/`.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem
i did tried to make sense of the script. i went through every line of code in js and yet i still can't understand how the images are being called from the online website. 

Thank you.

Comment: @Pietu1998 I'm concern with the buildings. The stars, sun and moon are working fine in the localhost. It is the buildings that are being called from the live website and i can't figure out why. I went through the js/css files and there seems to be no function that makes sense. Could you quickly check on it?

Comment: @nikitagupta OK, I just guessed it's the sun, moon & stars because of the code you include in the post. Also, now that I've looked around the JS files (there are many of them) the system to animate the page seems quite complicated; probably won't have time to look at it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In their style.css, they seem to have their images, like the stars, defined as background images. A lot of web designers seem to prefer for heavily-animated image elements, to use CSS and `background-image: url(...)` for them instead of including them as `<img>` elements. One reason, which I'm not sure is the case here, is it allows for "spriting", in which you have one image with about 15 important graphics on it, and then use CSS to tell a `<div>` to display a particular width/height of that image at a certain x/y offset. It also allows you to change something's image, or the particular sprite box of that image, by adding/removing classes to an element.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. However, I was talking about belfort.png, hotel.png, gentpoort.png, etc etc located in the "images/buildings" folder always being loaded from the parent ONLINE website although i've copied everything in the localhost.

I've gone through the zomer.min.js which has links to the images and .css files but couldn't understand why it still calls from the online website. How are they doing that? All other files are being called from the localhost.

Answer (score 0):

The animation are done in css.

for example the spinning star animations are done with this css code in style.css

```
#header #sunmoon .star {
    animation: 5s linear 0s normal none infinite spin;
    background: url("../images/star.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
    height: 26px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 26px;
}
```

note that the star is actually a background image: `url("../images/star.png")` 
and the spinning animation is done with the `animation` css rule.

Comment: Thanks. What i couldn't get are the buildings and other images such as belfort.png, hotel.png, gentpoort.png, etc etc located in the "images/buildings" folder always being loaded from the parent website although i've copied everything in the localhost.

After making a copy of the website in the http://localhost/visitbruges/, the images are being called from http://visitbruges.be/images/buildings/gentpoort.png etc

I've gone through the zomer.min.js which has links to the images and .css files but couldn't understand why it still calls from the online website.